# Test email sends from marketing tab in sfdc failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Our organisation is trying to connect our oem that sits on salesforce platform to the marketing cloud. The Marketing cloud connector is installed and set up is completed. We are now testing email sends..However we are encountering issues sending emails to test the connection.  We tried sending several emails using a report created in eom and an email created in content in sfmc. All email sends are failing with the following status error "cannot retrieve data". Not sure what we are missing since the installation and set up was  followed to the t? Test deliverability was completed successfully...
Any ideas?

Comment: Does the report contain the ContactId or LeadId column? and potentially also the email address?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, yes the report contained the ContactID. It would error if it didn't earlier in the process where I pick the recipients.

Comment: Ah right, forgot that piece. The report you are sending to, is that located in a non-standard folder that the integration user and sending user has access to?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, thank you for responding back! No the report we are sending to is saved  in the marketing cloud admin folder. I am thinking that maybe our oem  might need to enable sending emails at their end?or maybe there are restrictions at our infrastructure preventing email sends ... so we might have to look into this further...but at this stage we are not going to send email via the oem but may do so in the future..